# How to fix MeteorWebApp error: "Skipping downloading new version because the Cordova platform version or plugin versions have changed ..."?

Tags: java, android, cordova, meteor

I have an error when i run my app in my android device with:

```
meteor run android-device --settings settings.json --mobile-server=myip:port
```

I have deployed my app in my VPS with MUP (Meteor up). The app in my
device seems work good and is able to communicate with my VPS but i
have this error:

> E/MeteorWebApp(30703): Download failure
>
> E/MeteorWebApp(30703):com.meteor.webapp.WebAppException: Skipping
>   downloading new version because the Cordova platform version or plugin
>   versions have changed and are potentially incompatible I20160524
>
> E/MeteorWebApp(30703):    at
>   com.meteor.webapp.WebAppLocalServer.shouldDownloadBundleForManifest(WebAppLocalServer.java:367)
>
> E/MeteorWebApp(30703):    at
>   com.meteor.webapp.AssetBundleManager$1.onResponse(AssetBundleManager.java:131)
>
> ......

When I run with --verbose i have:

> D/MeteorWebApp( 4032): Detected new bundled version, removing
>   versions directory if it exists

My meteor project use:

- Meteor 1.3.3-beta.0
- cordova-android@5.1.1
- cordova:cordova-plugin-device v1.1.2

Comment: Was the app you have on your phone built using the same Meteor version and the same Cordova plugin versions as the one you have on your VPS?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried re-enabling android plaform:

```
meteor remove-platform android
meteor add-platform android
```

It solved my problem:

```
I20160729-21:30:01.571(2)? 07-29 21:30:01.342 10346 11702 E MeteorWebApp: Download failure
I20160729-21:30:01.572(2)? 07-29 21:30:01.342 10346 11702 E MeteorWebApp: com.meteor.webapp.WebAppException: Skipping downloading new version because the Cordova platform version or plugin versions have changed and are potentially incompatible
I20160729-21:30:01.572(2)? 07-29 21:30:01.342 10346 11702 E MeteorWebApp:   at com.meteor.webapp.WebAppLocalServer.shouldDownloadBundleForManifest(WebAppLocalServer.java:367)
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record, this error is an [intentional behaviour of Meteor](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#plugin-compatibility).

The idea is to block Hot Code Push when the Cordova version (or one of the Cordova plugins version) has changed, or if new Cordova plugins have been added to the Meteor project. The rationale is to prevent new code from reaching a device that will not be able to use it, because it will lack the associated Cordova plugins / versions (remember those [cannot be updated through Hot Code Push](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#updating-production-apps), but need a traditional update through App Store / Play Store).

There should be an option to force Meteor to proceed with the Hot Code Push no matter what, but I cannot find documentation on it unfortunately. I think a help message appears in the console during build when such a situation occurs (new Cordova plugins).

Comment: I've promised my customers that the Meteor version of mobile app will be updated automatically and I have no necessity to make new app publications. The only things which are really changed are my pure HTML/CSS/JavaScript. And those versions are changed. And I write migration code when users data can be incompatible with my new version. Meteor can't do that with its platform, that's sad. I understand that in the new version of Cordova which Meteor uses can be new features which could be incompatible with what I use, but why not try the backup / deploy / rollback process if something fails?

Comment: @IvanBorisenko I am not sure I understand your comment? If you have specific concerns, please feel free to open a new question or to use the Meteor forum.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added my comments on the Meteor GitHub issue about this. It seems many people want this feature. And I've suggested to think about install / rollback mechanism support instead of such dumb protection. Anyway, I'm not going to write a PR for the feature because I never more using Meteor in production: I was struggling with its bugs more than taking the only one useful feature: zero conf ESLast rebuild and hot code reload. Now it's useful only in development staging, and I'll advise all my colleagues do the same.

Comment: I'm not sure Meteor deserves such a negative review, but it is true that they tend to advertise features which are not yet stable or widely available. My rule of thumb: Don't tell the client about anything that I haven't tested myself.

Comment: Could this intentional behaviour be used to prevent Hot Code Push? Is there another way to prevent Hot Code Push?